# How to change pen movement speed on wacom tablet?

Tags: wacom

I tried to install the wacom tablet linux project thing, but when I did ./configure; make; make-install; it said there's no make file or something. I just need a way to change my pen movement speed. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please provide more details of exactly what you were trying to do, what you tried and what went wrong. And please also provide any error messages which were given.

Comment: I was trying to install http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/

Comment: sorry more info coming I didn't mean to press enter

Comment: I extracted it onto the desktop, then I tried to install it by using the commands ./configure; make; make-install. But I got the error,  "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop." I'm just trying to change my movement speed on my drawing tablet's pen.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: anyone? I could really use help with this

Answer (score 12):

### **Solution #1**

I'd suggest you check first if your tablet supports the `xsetwacom` speed parameter. To do this enter the terminal command:

```
xsetwacom --list parameters
```

This will output a list of possible `xsetwacom` parameters to set. Look for one called `Speed` or `SpeedLevel`. To slow the cursor movement speed down, set this parameter to a fraction of 1 (it is recommended not to go to far to down to 0), and to speed it up set this to a multiplication of 1. So for example to half the movement speed you'd do:

```
xsetwacom set <device id> Speed 0.5
```

You can find the device id by executing `xsetwacom --list devices`.
To have these changes set every time you boot, add that line to your `.xinitrc` file located in your home folder.

### **Solution #2** (worked for me, Intuos S)

If `xsetwacom` doesn't work, another, probably better way to do it is by using `xinput`. First detect the id's of your tablet again, by executing:

```
xinput list | grep Wacom
```

You should now see a couple of id's, the most important are stylus and eraser.
Then, find the attributes that set the constant deceleration, by executing this for as many device id's as you have (to exit press Ctrl+C):

```
xinput watch-props <device id>
```

You should see something like this in there:

```
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (284):   1.000000
```

The attribute's id is that number (in this case 284) at the end of the name.
Now in order to slow down the tablet movement, increase this number by executing:

```
xinput set-prop <device id> <attribute id> <deceleration factor>
```

An example:

```
xinput set-prop 13 284 2.5 && xinput set-prop 15 284 2.5
```

In this case, my stylus movement was device id 13 and my eraser id 15 so I set them both to 2.5, which as far as I could tell about halved the movement speed.

Again, these settings aren't saved at shutdown, so the best way is to have these settings be applied every time you boot. There are many ways to accomplish this, but an exapmle would be adding this command to you `.xinitrc` in your home folder. If this doesn't work, look for another way to have a command executed at boot on the internet.

**Sources** and credits:

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man4/wacom.4x.html
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1696260

**EDIT** #1: Added 2nd solution which worked better for myself.

**EDIT** #2: Grammar and sources

Comment: The second solution worked like a charm, thanks! Also, the 2.5 speed setting is just perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For mouse i'm using [mouse.sh](https://github.com/ford15focus/snippets/blob/master/sh/X/mouse.sh), maybe it is working for tablets too. I have no tablet and can't test.

Comment: repo was moved, https://pastebin.com/t7YD7cwi

Comment: removed from pastebin too

Answer (score 1):

I created a bash script to set the altered acceleration:

```
#!/bin/bash
device=$(xinput list | grep Wacom | grep stylus | grep -Po 'id=\K[^ ].')
property=$(xinput list-props $device | grep "Constant Deceleration" | grep -Po '\(\K[^\)]+')
xinput set-prop $device $property 2.0
```

(You might want to validate if it works per line before running the full script)